# Wordpress add custom roles as well as remove default roles

Tags: wordpress, roles

I need to customize the default roles as I need only 3 roles `- administrator, buyer, seller`.

Then I need to add the buyer, seller and remove all other default roles. What should I do?

If there is any ready made code which I can paste in and it will work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Paste this code in your themes function.php file and customize as your need. This is from my own code library. So it will definitely work.

```
/* Add member role to the site */
add_role('member', 'Member', array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
));

/* Add snypher role to the site */
add_role('snypher', 'Snypher', array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
));

/* remove the unnecessary roles */
remove_role('subscriber');
remove_role('editor');
remove_role('author');
remove_role('contributor');
```

Comment: Cool. I just like to note that this code needs to be executed only once, because it permanently changes the database. In my case I just added it to my functions.php, refreshed my admin page, and then removed the code again.

Comment: I tried this but could not delete the role. I wish to delete additional roles created by buddypress (I deleted buddypress) which is hindering another plugin.