# Wordpress Custom User Role

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a Developer role and give away for developers of a wordpress site. But in any case, I don't want them to change any important things (manage users, delete posts) of the site. May I know how to create a developer role (quite similar to admin) without user_management capabilities?

I've found below but couldn't figure out how to remove only user_management permission.

[Wordpress add custom roles as well as remove default roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413560/wordpress-add-custom-roles-as-well-as-remove-default-roles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) plugin very handy for this sort of thing. You can assign any combination of the standard WordPress capabilities to your newly created group. It's also great for protecting content in members' areas.